# Run a function after google translate translates a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm using the google translate dropdown on my site, and am wondering if anyone knows how to call a function *after* the translation occurs.

I need to adjust the height of some elements on my page to compensate for longer/shorter text.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using jQuery to invoke google translate?  Seems like you could use the standard callback approach after you get a response.  Here's [a link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) that shows how to invoke a callback function after performing a get request (see the "_success_" parameter... it's a callback function that gets invoked after the request).

Comment: hey thanks for the reply, i'll look into this. originally i was trying this approach:  

$('document').ready(function () {
    $(".some-google-selector").click(function() 
        $('.container').isotope({ sortBy : 'random' });
      });
  });
..trouble is the google language dropdown is an iframe so i can't really specify a selector.. looking for a workaround. thanks again!

Comment: I edited the tags for you... It looks like you're using jQuery and isotope (whatever that is)... I don't even know, but other people will.  Your question really isn't about translation... It's more about callbacks and AJAX (I assume you're using AJAX).  I recommend editing your question to list the tools and technologies you're using.  Add your code and ask a specific question and you'll probably get a quick answer.  Good luck!